# Error While submitting app to app store : ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: app-store, xcode8

My app development target is 8.0.

I am getting error while submitting app to app store and error is :

> ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New
>   iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display
>   on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the
>   Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to
>   {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the
>   top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you
>   localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app
>   launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at
>   https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen."

Comment: The answer is already in there. Did you add the requested launch images and optimized for the iPhone 5?